# Can you apply sha256 two times to a single string?

Tags: python, cryptography, sha256

I have wrote out the function:

```
print(hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(Encode(s))).hexdigest())
```

However, there seems to be the following error:

> object supporting the buffer API required

I believe this is because when hashing the second time, the input is not a byte form because it has been already hashed.

How can I solve this problem and hash a single string two times?

Comment: use `sha256.digest()`, not `sha256.hexdigest()`.

Comment: Thanks! However the question requests to print out a hexidecimal number. Then what should I do?

Comment: Well, you can certainly call `hexdigest()` for the final application of sha256, or you can call the `hex()` method on the resulting bytes object instead. The choice is yours, do some experiments. And just to be clear, the question never asks to print out a hex value.

Comment: What does `Encode` do here? That's likely the culprit. If you're not sure where your error is generated, then frickin' *split the line* into multiple statements.

Answer (score 0):

How about this code (as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851915/can-you-apply-sha256-two-times-to-a-single-string#comment96478734_54851915) by [james-k-polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/james-k-polk))?

```
print(hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(s.encode('ascii')).digest()).hexdigest())
```

Answer (score -1):

This works if you want to do it in one line

```
from hashlib import sha256 as h
print(h(h("your_string".encode()).hexdigest().encode()).hexdigest())

# Gives: c94c01dafc045892773d67dabb3da8feb925e2c48e0373eab922da49f7fd269c
# Encrypted once: e10207f241d66a8c5f8202ed9fc22b94c031850dd54d8b03fdd40db4cbde5bfc
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please mark this as the answer to thanks me for my time.

Comment: This returns the wrong result, because it returns the hash over the hexadecimal encoding instead of the byte values themselves.